# React native web view Android back button not exit the app

Tags: android, react-native

React native web view Android back button not exit the app. When i pressed back button it will not exixt the app. The following are my sample code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () => {
    const webview = useRef(null);
    const onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (webview.current) {
      webview.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    };
    }, []);

    return (
    <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }} ref={webview}/>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [a method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler#exitapp) in Backhandler for exiting app. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried but app not exit.it struck on first page when press android back button.

Comment: Can you share the code that you used Backhandler.exitApp() ?

Comment: I am used the above code. Which is pasted in above.

Comment: I do not see any Backhandler.exitApp() method in the above code ? Did you maybe forget to update it ?

Comment: If I add Backhandler.exitApp(). It will kill the app. But I want kill the app when no any pages history

Comment: So you just want to exit from webview, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. Let me explain. Suppose if you browse 3 page and when you press back button it will take you 2 page then page 1 after that app kill

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241798/discussion-between-bob-kris-and-tarik).